# React: Run handler, only at select renders, useCallback or useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to run a function only when the variable `phone` (see below) changes.

*Note: `useMediaQuery` works as intended, it initiates re-render whenever the screen size changes above / below 768, and returns true / false.*

```
const phone = !useMediaQuery('(min-width:768px)'); // 768 and down: Smartphones

console.log('phone', phone);
useCallback(() => {
  console.log('useCallback fired');
  if (!phone) handleDrawerClose();
}, [phone])();
```

My above code fires the callback in `useCallback` on every re-render. Regardless if `phone` changed. I tried `useEffect` and it partially works.

Why does not `useCallback` work as intended?

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useCallback` returns a memoized function, which you then call. As you call it, it gets executed.

> What is the best approach here?

`useEffect`

Comment: Thank you. 1) Is it not the case that the function in `useCallback` should **only** run if the specified dependency changes? 2) Why is `useEffect` the right choice here?

Comment: To quote the `useCallback` docs: "This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders". And no, the returned memoized function gets executed when you call it.